# Applying a DataTemplateSelector in a Custom Control Style

Tags: wpf, datatemplateselector

I am developing a custom control which descends from a ListBox. As part of my control, I want to provide a default ItemTemplateSelector. Unfortunately, I can't see to get it to find my DataTemplateSelector. Here is the code, with irrelevant details elided:

```
public class AnnotationTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate BoxValuePairTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        return BoxValuePairTemplate;
    }
}
```

And the Xaml...

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="BoxValuePairDataTemplate">
        <Grid TextBlock.FontSize="9" Height="13" Width="{Binding Path=Width}" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
     ... etc...
        </Grid>                                  
     </DataTemplate>
```

The selector:

```
    <Annotations:AnnotationTemplateSelector BoxValuePairTemplate="{StaticResource BoxValuePairDataTemplate}"
                                            x:Key="AnnotationTemplateSelector" />
```

The style:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Annotations:BoxEditorSurface}">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplateSelector" Value="{StaticResource AnnotationTemplateSelector}"/>
        ... etc ...
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>

                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    </Style>
```

Unfortunately, after the template is applied, the ItemTemplateSelector is always null, and no binding errors are shown.

Ideas?

Comment: I suspect the key "annotationTemplateSelector" instead of "AnnotationTemplateSelector" is a typo? You'd get an exception otherwise...

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. The problem turned out to be in some of the elided details. I'm posting an update now.

Comment: Is your style applied? Is the selector defined "above" the style? Did you have for any reason an ItemTemplate set, because the selector is ignored(maybe nulled) when an ItemTemplate is found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out I was missing a binding in the ContentPresenter. I'm providing my answer now in hopes it will prevent frustration for whomever might make the same mistake in future:

```
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                              ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplateSelector}"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>

                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

I was missing the ContentTemplateSelector Binding in the ContentPresenter, so it was obviously never invoked.